# Rails controllers architecture with many to many relationships and modal dialogs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, architecture, modal-dialog, naming-conventions

I am developing a portal via RubyOnRails where pupils, teachers and parents can participate in different contests with their art works.

There are 3 entities: `Contests`, `Categories` (competitor categories / age groups) and `Nominations` (kinds of activity). `Contest` can have many `Categories`. Each `ContestCategory` can have many `Nominations`. Each `Category` can belong to several `Contests`. Every `Nomination` can belong to many `ContestCategories`. So I presume there is many-to-many relationship between `Contests` and `Categories` and many-to-many relationship between `ContestCategories` and `Nominations`. I've created following models: `Contest` (contest.rb), `Category` (category.rb), `Nomination` (nomination.rb), `ContestCategory` (contest_category.rb) and `ContestCategoryNomination` (contest_category_nomination.rb).

My models:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contest_categories
  has_many :contests, through: :contest_categories
end

class Contest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contest_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :contest_categories
  has_many :nominations, through: :contest_categories
  has_one :provision
end

class ContestCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contest
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :contest_category_nominations
  has_many :nominations, through: :contest_category_nominations
end

class ContestCategoryNomination < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contest_category
  belongs_to :nomination
end

class Nomination < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contest_category_nominations
  has_many :contest_categories, through: :contest_category_nominations
  has_many :contests, through: :contest_categories
end
```

I want to create an ajax-based modal window during creation of new `Contest` to link it with `Category` and select multiple `Nominations` that belong to this `Category`.

1. What controllers should I create to satisfy has_many relationships
   between my models?
2. What are the naming conventions (singular and plural) in rails to satisfy my
   relationships? For example, `ContestsCategoriesController` or
   `ContestCategoryNominationsController` or may be
   `ContestCategoryNominationsController`?
3. What action method should I create in this controllers to invoke to
   render this modal window? Should it be `new_category` action in
   `CategoriesController` or `new` action in `ContestsCategoriesController`
   or `new` action in `ContestsCategoriesNominationsController`?

Comment: Do you want to create or update the associated objects (contest, category and nomination) in one form or in several forms?

Comment: I'm planning to create/update categories and nominations in modal form so after closing it will transfer data into the main form (create/edit contest page) and saving the contest will also invoke the saving of linked to it categories and nominations. At least it is the only solution came to my mind.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? Or do you need more help?

Comment: And what if I decide to link category/nominations to contests on a single page? For example, by defining a partial that renders when I'm pressing "add category" button on New Contest page.

Answer (score 0):

That completely depends on how you want to manipulate your objects. If you only want to modify all attributes and relations through Contests, you'd just need the ContestsController. Using a nifty little method like `accept_nested_attributes_for` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html you can provide all relevant values, even to the associated records.

Comment: accept_nested_attributes_for is considered harmful. It is brittle and hard to maintain, because it couples the nested objects even harder in the view. It makes sense to create form objects (a class, that deals with those nested objects) and use an equivalent controller to represent that class.

Answer (score 0):

Referring on your requirement you noted in the comments, I'd create a form in the modal dialogue, which represent a form object, like:

```
class Nomination::Category
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  # validates :your_attributes

  def initialize(category, attributes = {})
    @category = category
    @attributes = attributes
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  def save
    return false unless valid?
    if create_objects
      # after saving logic
    else
      false
    end
  end
  # more business logic according to your requirements
private
  def create_objects
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      # @category.contests = ... saving logic
      @category.save!
    end
  rescue
    false
  end
end
```

and a representing controller:

```
class NominationCategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    category = Category.find params[:category_id]
    @nomination_category = Nomination::Category.new category
  end

 def create
   category = Category.find params[:category_id]
   @nomination_category = Nomination::Category.new category, params[:nomination_category]
   @nomination_category.save
 end
end
```

Please beware this is just an example/idea. The concrete implementation depends on your specific business logic requirements.

It worth reading [more about the form objects approach](http://chris-on-rails.blogspot.de/2015/05/clean-up-nested-forms-with-form-objects.html).

Comment: I do not understand this construction: `Nomination::Category`. I read this as "Category in the namespace of Nomination". But, conversely, Nomination belongs to Category (which belongs to Contest in its turn; here Category == ContestCategory), not Category to Nomination.

Comment: Well. If I mixed up your specific associations, please be forgiven. You then should invert then namespace thing. But the key of that answer is to use a form object, which represents your workflow or form.